# Ways to add a certificate to the certificate store from a script

Tags: windows, security

I want to install a certificate in the certificate store. Is there a way to do it from a script. Meaning one of the following is true:

- There is a console utility, which then can be invoked from a batch script.
- There is a COM object, which can be instantiated from a VB script.
- Adding to the certificate store boils down to some basic operations (like registry or file system changes), which can then be performed from a script.

There may exist other options, which I do not see. In anyway, I want to be able to install into the certificate store of my choice in the unattended mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CertMgr.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0%28VS.80%29.aspx) can be used from the command line.